# How to center an image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center some images regardless of their width.

Here is an example page http://www.shoezies.co.nz/product-category/collection+bags/

You will see some of the smaller images of bags are left aligned.I've tried doing margin: 0 auto; but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using absolute position try this,

```
img{
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give this css,it will solved your issue

```
.show-product-thumb img {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto!important;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with text align centre, or keep image in a p tag

```
img{
text-align: center;
}

p{
  text-align: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the position absolute property in `.show-product-thumb img`

```
.show-product-thumb img {
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* left: 0; */
    /* bottom: 0; */
}
```

and add `text-align: center;` in `.show-product-thumb`

```
.show-product-thumb {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have 4 colmen that mean 100%/4=25% and that should be your `li` `width` and the `max-with:250px` should be set to the `a` element try adding this class :

```
 .woocommerce ul.products li.product a {
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
max-width: 244px;
}
```

and edit this class :

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
float: left;
margin:0px !important; /* set the margin to the inner element "a" */
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 25% !important;/* 100%/4=25% */
}
```

then remove the `absolute position` from yur `img` by editing this class :

```
.show-product-thumb img{
/* position: absolute; */ /*no need for absolute position*/
/* left: 0; */ /*no need for left position*/
/* bottom: 0; */ /*no need for bottom position*/
overflow: hidden;
margin: auto !important;/* and this would center your image */
max-width: 100% !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add below css for image for center align. That will work well.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  box-shadow: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do like below with just text-align:center, in your code you mentioned position:absolute to image inside the li. Just by removing that and apply text-align:center to its parent will gives the expected result

Else

If its necessary to have position:absolute; to your image tag then simply add right:0 !important; margin:0 auto; to your image tag.

```css
.show-product-thumb img{
  position:relative !important;
}
.show-product-thumb{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/plugins/shoezies/css/style.css?ver=0.4">

<li class="post-9983 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-bags product_cat-collection last instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" style="height: 281px;">
 <a href="http://www.shoezies.co.nz/product/campomaggi-square-back-pack-khaki/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
  <div class="show-product-thumb" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;">
   <img src="//www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-24_3679-225x150.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="//www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-24_3679-225x150.jpg 225w, //www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-24_3679.jpg 900w, //www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-24_3679-768x510.jpg 768w, //www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-24_3679-450x300.jpg 450w" sizes="(max-width: 225px) 100vw, 225px" width="225" height="150">
  </div>
  <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Campomaggi Square Back Pack (Khaki)</h2>
  <p>Khaki backpack made from canvas and leather with military applique. Something wonderfully different from the clever people at Campomaggi in Italy</p>
  <span class="price">
   <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>572.00
   </span>
  </span>
 </a>
 <a rel="nofollow" href="/product-category/collection+bags/?add-to-cart=9983" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="9983" data-product_sku="campomaggi-square-back-pack-khaki" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>
</li>

<li class="post-9983 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-bags product_cat-collection last instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" style="height: 281px;">
 <a href="http://www.shoezies.co.nz/product/campomaggi-square-back-pack-khaki/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
  <div class="show-product-thumb" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;">
   <img src="//www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-17_3397-1-134x150.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="//www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-17_3397-1-134x150.jpg 134w, //www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-17_3397-1-267x300.jpg 267w, //www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-17_3397-1.jpg 623w" sizes="(max-width: 134px) 100vw, 134px" width="134" height="150">
  </div>
  <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Campomaggi Square Back Pack (Khaki)</h2>
  <p>Khaki backpack made from canvas and leather with military applique. Something wonderfully different from the clever people at Campomaggi in Italy</p>
  <span class="price">
   <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>572.00
   </span>
  </span>
 </a>
 <a rel="nofollow" href="/product-category/collection+bags/?add-to-cart=9983" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="9983" data-product_sku="campomaggi-square-back-pack-khaki" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>
</li>

<li class="post-9983 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-bags product_cat-collection last instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" style="height: 281px;">
 <a href="http://www.shoezies.co.nz/product/campomaggi-square-back-pack-khaki/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
  <div class="show-product-thumb" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;">
   <img src="//www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-06_3165-100x150.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="//www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-06_3165-100x150.jpg 100w, //www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-06_3165-199x300.jpg 199w, //www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-06_3165.jpg 465w" sizes="(max-width: 100px) 100vw, 100px" style="/*! top: 50%; *//*! bottom: 50%; */transform: translate (50%, 50%);margin: 0 auto;" width="100" height="150">
  </div>
  <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Campomaggi Square Back Pack (Khaki)</h2>
  <p>Khaki backpack made from canvas and leather with military applique. Something wonderfully different from the clever people at Campomaggi in Italy</p>
  <span class="price">
   <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>572.00
   </span>
  </span>
 </a>
 <a rel="nofollow" href="/product-category/collection+bags/?add-to-cart=9983" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="9983" data-product_sku="campomaggi-square-back-pack-khaki" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>
</li>

<li class="post-9983 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-bags product_cat-collection last instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" style="height: 281px;">
 <a href="http://www.shoezies.co.nz/product/campomaggi-square-back-pack-khaki/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
  <div class="show-product-thumb" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;">
   <img src="//www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-06_3165-100x150.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="//www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-06_3165-100x150.jpg 100w, //www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-06_3165-199x300.jpg 199w, //www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-06_3165.jpg 465w" sizes="(max-width: 100px) 100vw, 100px" style="/*! top: 50%; *//*! bottom: 50%; */transform: translate (50%, 50%);margin: 0 auto;" width="100" height="150">
  </div>
  <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Campomaggi Square Back Pack (Khaki)</h2>
  <p>Khaki backpack made from canvas and leather with military applique. Something wonderfully different from the clever people at Campomaggi in Italy</p>
  <span class="price">
   <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>572.00
   </span>
  </span>
 </a>
 <a rel="nofollow" href="/product-category/collection+bags/?add-to-cart=9983" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="9983" data-product_sku="campomaggi-square-back-pack-khaki" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>
</li>

<li class="post-9983 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-bags product_cat-collection last instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple" style="height: 281px;">
 <a href="http://www.shoezies.co.nz/product/campomaggi-square-back-pack-khaki/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
  <div class="show-product-thumb" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;">
   <img src="//www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-06_3165-100x150.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="//www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-06_3165-100x150.jpg 100w, //www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-06_3165-199x300.jpg 199w, //www.shoezies.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/MFW_2017-11-06_3165.jpg 465w" sizes="(max-width: 100px) 100vw, 100px" style="/*! top: 50%; *//*! bottom: 50%; */transform: translate (50%, 50%);margin: 0 auto;" width="100" height="150">
  </div>
  <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Campomaggi Square Back Pack (Khaki)</h2>
  <p>Khaki backpack made from canvas and leather with military applique. Something wonderfully different from the clever people at Campomaggi in Italy</p>
  <span class="price">
   <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>572.00
   </span>
  </span>
 </a>
 <a rel="nofollow" href="/product-category/collection+bags/?add-to-cart=9983" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="9983" data-product_sku="campomaggi-square-back-pack-khaki" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `absolute` positioning has already been declared on these product thumbnails (`.show-product-thumb img`), all that needs to be added in addition to the existing styles is a `right` property with a defined value and a reset `margin` property value, e.g:

#### How it's currently aligned:

```
.show-product-thumb img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

#### What you need to add:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .show-product-thumb img {
    right: 0;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

*Note:* more *specificity* has been added to the above selectors to *over-qualify* existing WooCommerce styles without the need to use the `!important` declaration.

**For future reference:**
*CodePen practical demonstrations*

1. [Horizontal Alignment (Arbitrary Elements)](https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/vWGbdb)
2. [Horizontal Alignment (Text Elements)](https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/BmKMra)
3. [Vertical Alignment (Arbitrary Elements)](https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/XzdGqO)
4. [Vertical Alignment (Text Elements)](https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/rYeRoR)